# App Fabric crash with XCode

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I use Fabric App for declare or add components fabric (Crashlytics, Answer, ...), but for several hours, the application crashes once Xcode has compiled the application successfully.

Scenario:

1. Add Run Script Build Phase: ./Fabric.framework/run XXXXXXXXXXXX
2. App Fabric is pending
3. Build my project with XCode with Success
4. App Fabric Crash ->

`

```
Process:               Fabric [28573]
Path:                  /private/var/folders/*/Fabric.app/Contents/MacOS/Fabric
Identifier:            com.crashlytics.mac
Version:               2.7.1 (1292)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Fabric [28573]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-08-10 12:10:29.132 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        6E2B16E4-1A52-ECA6-C4C9-95784265343F


Time Awake Since Boot: 6800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Notes:                 Translocated Process

Crashed Thread:        7  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x600000028b60 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000111a96400
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x111a96400:
    mapped file            0000000111669000-0000000111a69000 [ 4096K] r--/r-x SM=PRV  Object_id=8dbb241f
--> 
    MALLOC_NANO            0000600000000000-0000600000c00000 [ 12.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff5c2ada16 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff5c476589 _pthread_cond_wait + 732
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff364dbdd0 -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 896
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff364395ff -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 238
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3432bedc __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3432bdaa _CFXRegistrationPost + 458
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3432bae1 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 225
```

`

I try download new version of Fabric, restart Mac, etc -> Same result.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Hmm, very strange. Can you share your Fabric init code?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure understand "Fabric init code". What exactly do you need?

Comment: The code you used to start Fabric  -       Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self]) - for example.

Comment: I tried Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self]) or Fabric.with([]), it's same... Also, I try a create a new xcode project (without init Fabric), and add Run Phase Script "/Fabric.framework/run XXXXXXXXXXXX", then compile with successful, and Fabric crash...

Comment: Can you try updating to Beta 6? We saw some other bugs fixed from that.

Comment: Beta 6 ? Fabric.app ? If yes, where can dowload it ?

Comment: Beta 6 of Xcode.

Comment: Not work.

1/ I installed XCode 10 BETA 6
2/ create empty project 
3/ Launch Fabric
4/ Add Run Phase Script with my key (provded by fabric)
5/ Add Fabric my api key in Info.plist
6/ Open my new project in Fabric
7/ Fabric in wait
8/ Build Project with XCode with Successful
9/ Fabric Crash....

I did a lot of testing, but nothing seems to work.
Before this situation happened (a few days ago), I erased the old project application from the Fabric dashboard. Is there a way to add a project manually?

Comment: There are manual setup instructions, but not a manual activation. Can you email support(at)fabric(dot)io so we can get some more logs? Feel free to reference this thread and my name.

Comment: Had the same issue. Disappeared after upgrading Xcode10 to Version 10.0 beta 6 (10L232m)